# Configuring Path and CORS for Socket.io Node Apps on Microsoft Azure

Tags: node.js, azure, socket.io, azure-web-app-service

I'm working on a Node.js application that uses Socket.io for real-time communication. I'm deploying this application on Microsoft Azure, and I'm having trouble configuring the path and CORS settings for my WebSocket connections. Specifically, I want to set different paths and CORS origins for various parts of my application. Below is a simplified version of my code:

## Server Configuration:

```
import { createServer } from "http";
import express from "express";
import { Server } from "socket.io";

const app = express();
const server = createServer(app);
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000;

// Setting up Socket.io for "spareparty"
let ioSpareParty = gameRoutes.setIoSpare(server);
useAzureSocketIO(ioSpareParty, {
  hub: "spare_hub",
  connectionString: process.argv[2] || process.env.WebPubSubConnectionString,
});

ioSpareParty.on("connection", spareParity);

// More code here...

const start = async () => {
  try {
    await connectDB(databaseUrl);
    server.listen(PORT, console.log("Server running at " + PORT));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

start();
```

## Socket.io Configuration:

```
// Inside "_iospareparity.js"
const setIoSpare = (server) => {
  _ioSpareParty = new Server(server, {
    path: "/api/v1/games/spareparty", // What should be the path here ?
    cors: {
      origin: "http://localhost:5173", // What should be the origin here ?
      methods: ["GET", "POST"],
      allowedHeaders: [
        "Origin",
        "X-Requested-With",
        "Content-Type",
        "Accept",
        "Authorization",
      ],
      credentials: true,
      optionSuccessStatus: 200,
    },
  });

  return _ioSpareParty;
};
```

I want to configure WebSocket path and CORS settings for "spareparty," "fastparty," and "easyparty" parts of my application. Ensure that each part has its own distinct path and CORS origin.
What steps should I follow to achieve this configuration on Microsoft Azure? Are there any specific settings I need to adjust in Azure's configuration, or should I make changes in my code? Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated.

## Package.json File:

```
{
  "name": "hello",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "app.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js",
    "server": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@azure/web-pubsub-socket.io": "^1.0.0-beta.6",
    "axios": "^1.5.0",
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.43",
    "mongodb": "^5.7.0",
    "mongoose": "^7.4.3",
    "node-cron": "^3.0.2",
    "node-schedule": "^2.1.1",
    "otp-generator": "^4.0.1",
    "socket.io": "^4.7.2",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.7.2",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "description": ""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Node.js application on Azure should have the distinct WebSocket paths and CORS settings for different parts of the application as shown in below.

[image]

- Create separate Socket.io instances for each part.

```js
// Inside your server configuration
const server = createServer(app);
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000;
const databaseUrl = "..."; // Your database URL

const ioSpareParty = setIoSpare(server, "/api/v1/games/spareparty", "http://localhost:5173");
const ioFastParty = setIoSpare(server, "/api/v1/games/fastparty", "http://your-fastparty-origin");
const ioEasyParty = setIoSpare(server, "/api/v1/games/easyparty", "http://your-easyparty-origin");

ioSpareParty.on("connection", spareParity);
// Add similar connection handlers for ioFastParty and ioEasyParty

// More code here...

const start = async () => {
  try {
    await connectDB(databaseUrl);
    server.listen(PORT, console.log("Server running at " + PORT));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

start();
```

- Change `setIoSpare` function to accept the path and origin as parameters ("spareparty," "fastparty," and "easyparty").

```js
const setIoParty = (server, path, origin) => {
  const ioParty = new Server(server, {
    path: `/api/v1/games/${path}`,
    cors: {
      origin: origin,
      methods: ["GET", "POST"],
      allowedHeaders: [
        "Origin",
        "X-Requested-With",
        "Content-Type",
        "Accept",
        "Authorization",
      ],
      credentials: true,
      optionSuccessStatus: 200,
    },
  });

  return ioParty;
};
```

By this Each Socket.io instance will use its specified path and origin and they can communicate independently.